# How can I open multiple forms in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, datagrid

I have a DataGridView with data loaded from a database. Each row has a 'View' button and when I click on it another form is opened with specific information but the main form with the DataGridView is still opened. I do this with this code:

```
FormView fr = new FormView(id);
fr.ShowDialog();
```

The problem is that I can't open several FormViews at the same time because the focus is still in the first FormView opened. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you use ShowDialog on a form it shows and waits for a response of type DialogeResult, but when you just need to show a form and no response is needed you can simply call form.Show()
here is the code :

When you want a result:

```
Form f = new Form(); 
DialogResult res = f.ShowDialog();  

//code stops here until you return something of type DialogResult  
if (res == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)  
    I_Will_Run_Just_When_DialogReult_Returned_Is_OK();
```

when you only want to show the form:

```
f.Show();  
I_Will_Run_Anyway_Right_After_Showing_Form();
```

Answer (score 3):

`ShowDialog` opens a modal form which means that the `ShowDialog` method won't return until the user has closed the form.

Use `fr.Show` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this

```
fr.ShowDialog();
```

to

```
fr.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
FormView fr = new FormView(id);  
fr.Show();
```

to show them non modally so execution can continue and allow you to show more.